# Ambiguous Reference

Tags: asp.net

In my WAP project, every .aspx's code-behind and designer share the same namespace.  For example my Main.Master.cs and Main.designer.cs are both in the OurCompany.Web namespace by default.

When I go to another .aspx page and use the following, I get an "Ambiguous reference" error because it can't decide if I'm talking about my code-behind or designer file of that master page

```
<%@ MasterType  TypeName="OurCompany.Web.Main" %>
```

but by default this is the way VS creates .aspx pages so should I really care?

Answer (score 2):

The designer files are all marked as "partial" classes so they don't get compiled into their own types.

My guess is that you really do have 2 classes called "OurCompany.Web.Main".  A tool like Reflector would let you browser your DLLs so you could tell for sure.

Comment: I don't have 2 classes and all of my code behind classes are getting this problem.  I wonder if I just needed to clean my solution

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me, your problem is the JIT compilation creating temporary "copies" of your assemblies in a temp directory.

Make sure every namespace/partial class declaration is "tight", check for incorrect class names, wrong namespaces.

The problem "just went away" for me as well.  Recreating or cleaning the solution will probably do it. Wish I could be more helpful but going cleaning up the source, both manually and with the right click menu probably helped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have a master page and a web form page with the same name on the code behind class.  And this will prevent your site from working correctly (if it works at all).

I'd go through my aspx.cs files and looking for the class name main (find should work here).  I bet you will find two files with the name.  You will have to change one of them to something else.  Just make sure you also change the Inherits in the .aspx page and the .designer.cs class name.

Comment: but every .aspx.cx is showing double types.  Not just the Master

Comment: weird cause I just setup this same solution structure again and now the problem is gone.